# How to patch crates-io with path using Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my Rust crate I need to be able to use 2 git repositories both checked out in the root of my crate. They are both modified and pkg_b requires an older version of `pkg_a`, `0.1.0`. I can't seem to get `pkg_b` to use the newer version of pkg_a, `0.2.0`. My current workaround has been to just update the Cargo.toml file in pkg_b.

My crate's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "mypkg"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
pkg_a = { path = "./pkg_a" } # This is 0.2.0 with my changes added
pkg_b = { path = "./pkg_b" }

[patch.crates-io]
pkg_a = { path = "./pkg_a", features = ["serde_support"] }
```

And pkg_b's `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "pkg_b"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
pkg_a = { version = "0.1.0", features = ["serde_support"] }
```

Answer (score 2):

If `pkg_b` requires `pkg_a ^0.1.0` (meaning "between `0.1.0` and `0.2.0`", see [caret requirements in Cargo](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#caret-requirements)), you can't make it accept `pkg_a 0.2.0` as a dependency, even if you patch the registry to make local `pkg_a` repository discoverable. Maintaining a patch for `pkg_b/Cargo.toml` seems like your best bet.